# How can i schedule automatically print jobs?

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, struts

at present for every 15 min , manually i am entering 'one code' in text box(eg: trip code(travel domain project)) which is already exist in database, if it is valid code then showing report in HTML format then taking print out. Now my requirement like this after every 15 min , i have schedule print job automatically , with out entering trip code. ( trip code examples are :  `0015 , 0030, 0045.0200..............these are 00:15 am hrs,  00:30hrs, 2 hrs` Am  timings..)  platform : java, struts, jsp

Answer (score 2):

You need some type of Scheduling recurring tasks one API which came in my mind is

```
java.util.Timer and java.util.TimerTask
```

and if you want something more powerful and more configurable you can always reply upon Quartz Scheduler

[quartz-scheduler](http://quartz-scheduler.org/)

Comment: Hi Naveen , i am trying to download Quartz Software for windows, only .tar is available in official site , can u plz help me  where can i download and how to install?

Comment: @hari: i hope you have `winRAR` in your window machine, just download it and extract it using `winRAR`.